# Buscar un Dato en un Datagridview sin especificar Columnas

Tags: c#, datagrid, datagridview, c#-8.0

Necesito buscar en un **DataGridView** un Dato "X", que esta en "Y" Columna... Ya que mi **DGV** tiene varias formas de llenado dependiendo que consulta haga a la base de datos se llenara.

El caso que el código que hasta ahora tengo es el siguiente:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow Row in resultadosdelaconsulta.Rows)
        {
            String strFila = Row.Index.ToString();
            string Valor = Convert.ToString(Row.Cells["Estado"].Value);

            if (Valor == this.BuscarEnDGB.Text)
            {
                resultadosdelaconsulta.Rows[Convert.ToInt32(strFila)].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
        }
```

Este código esta dentro de un botón... el resultado por ejemplo si busco **NUEVA** me va a buscar en la Columna **Estado**. Si se encuentra "NUEVA"  me pintara las filas que coincidan. De esta manera:

[image: Aqui lleno mi DataGridView con las polizas y busco la palabra NUEVA]

Ahora bien, si en vez de querer buscar "NUEVA" quiero buscar "Algún numero de póliza" o "un numero de serie"... Mi DataGridView se llena con consultas como= "Polizas", "Tarjetas","Pagos" etc... y como es el mismo datagridview que utilizo no tengo las columnas iguales para todas las consultas.

Espero y me haya explicado bien y puedan ayduarme. De ante mano Muchas Gracias!.

Comment: Deseas que busque en cualquier columna? o que primero encuentre la columna por su titulo y luego busque solo en ella?

Comment: @F.Igor deseo buscar en Cualquier columna ya que el DGV se llenan según la consulta que haga a la base de datos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el caso de buscar en cualquier columna deberas recorrer tambien cada columna de cada fila:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow Row in resultadosdelaconsulta.Rows)
    {
        String strFila = Row.Index.ToString();
        foreach(DataGridViewCell cell in Row.Cells)
            {
              string Valor = Convert.ToString(cell.Value);
              if (Valor == this.BuscarEnDGB.Text)
                  {
resultadosdelaconsulta.Rows[Convert.ToInt32(strFila) ].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: Perfecto!, Muchas Gracias.

Comment: Bro... te puedo molestar con otra consulta?...

Comment: Hola Jesus, haz la pregunta en otro post y la revisaré sin duda